# Is a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error a complete dead end

Tags: vue.js, rest, cors, progressive-web-apps

I've gotten this error trying to pull resources from an api using a front end app:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've seen a lot of debate about this on SO.  I want to present a very simple question.

I am in no way, capable of changing the back end on this REST server (I don't own it).
The app I'm developing is a PWA.
Am I screwed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am in no way, capable of changing the back end on this REST server (I don't own it).

Then you can't change the headers at all. You would have to proxy it through your own backend. AFAIK no frontend network calls will override this (not even service worker interceptions)